# Why am I listed twice?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

Just curious, I am new and getting used to some of the features of SE. I went to my profile and it said I was in the top 2%. So, I clicked on the link and started navigating through the list of users until I got to the bottom.

I was listed only once initially. Then I clicked to page #2 and then pressed the show 50 and I noticed I came up twice.

I may have missed something but why would I be listed twice? I am number 1 and 2. I can't be the first AND second most gainful user for the week. Is this a bug?

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/229/week/ell/2014-11-16?sort=reputationchange&pagesize=50

Comment: Do the numbers in the box actually say 1 and 2? Or do they both say 1? The leaderboards will *always* list you at the very top of the list, highlighted in a yellow box to say "this is you." You will still *also* appear wherever you would normally appear in the actual list. So if you're #1, then you should be listed twice one after another.

Comment: ah, no. It says #1 on both. I just found it odd I was listed twice. It didn't do this on the first page so it stood out and didn't look uniform.

Comment: You might not have been logged in yet when you viewed the first page. Then when the system logged you in again and you changed the page, it threw you off.

Comment: So, I get logged in automatically everytime I switch sites? I thought it was seamless. I never noticed I was being logged in (only when I first sign up for a new site.)

Comment: If you've been to that site before and it remembers you, yes it will log you in automatically if your previous session had expired. When it does so, there should be a white box up at the top of your screen saying it logged you back in.

Comment: This reminds me of when another user topped Jon Skeet on the reputation league.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug.

> I was listed only once initially.

When you click on the link that says "top x%" on any user's profile, it takes shows you the league and highlights the row of the respective user for you. You can see that the url contains the user id in this case. For example, if you click the "top x% on [animuson's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)", it displays the league with his row highlighted and his userid appended to the url. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta/2014-01-01/141525#141525

This view is consistent irrespective of your user session (verify by logging out or using incognito mode). This shows the user only once.

> Then I clicked to page #2 and then pressed the show 50 and I noticed I came up twice.

When you navigate in the league, the userid is no longer present in the url as a parameter. It identifies you from your user session.
The url is of the form: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/month/meta

### View for logged in user:

[image: logged in image]

### View for anonymous user (no highlighted row):

[image: view without login]

If you are logged in, the top row always displays your stats, and is highlighted. The rest of the league is displayed below it. As a result, if you are #1, you can see yourself twice. For example, I see myself twice. If you aren't logged in (or in incognito mode), you will see the league without any repetitions.